# Flexbox does not vertically align

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need some help vertically aligning the following table. 
I can not understand the reason why it doesn't vertically align.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dabt5z3y/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it with this style:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Without this, the body's height takes up only enough space to hold its content.

### Fiddle

Comment: Really about is scored. Thank you very much.